# PHP autoloading classes

Tags: php, autoload

It's my first time using autoloading but I keep getting the error saying my class can't be found:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Classes\Sunrise\DB' not found in my\sample\path\.sunrise.app\init.php on line 52
```

**Edit:** Line 52 is where I use a static method from the DB class. For some reason, PHP says it can't find the DB class.

My structure:

```
order (Folder)
    + index.php 
.sunrise.app
    + init.php
    + ordersetup.php
    + Classes (Folder)
        + Sunrise (Folder)
            + DB.php
```

The file `init.php` contains my autoloader and is included in the file `ordersetup.php` which in turn is included in `order/index.php` with `include_once '../.sunrise.app/ordersetup.php';` In the file `.sunrise.app/init.php` I need to use the DB class but am met with the error shown above. What am I doing wrong?

My autoloader in `.sunrise.app/init.php`:

```
function my_autoload($class_name) {
  include $class_name. '.php';
}
spl_autoload_register('my_autoload');
```

My DB class in `classes/Sunrise/DB.php`:

```
<?php namespace Classes\Sunrise;

use PDO;

class DB { ... }
```

**Edit:** The folder `Sunrise` is under the folder `Classes`

Comment: You use Classes in the namespace, but classes in the folder hierarchy. Is this a linux system? Beware of correct casing. Use require instead of include to trigger a fatal error if the file does not exist.

Comment: My mistake, the `classes` folder is actually `Classes`. It's capitalized.

Comment: Your `use PDO` statement will call the autoloader for a class called `PDO` in the `Classes\Sunrise` namespace. If you want the `PDO` from the global namespace, you'll have to write `use \PDO`, where the leading `\` references the global namespace

Comment: try removing the dot from the beginning of .sunrise.app in both the directory name as well as the autoloader. These file paths are generally ignored by apache. Or as a test try to `require` one of these files manually.

Comment: Removed the dot. Didn't work. Although I had my doubts since I don't think folder names can affect the outcome of paths.

Answer (score 1):

since the seperators are `\` you need to replace them with the correct directory seperator for the OS, if this is a linux os then they need to be `/`

```
function my_autoload($class_name) {
  $class_name = str_replace("\\","/",$class_name);
  require "../.sunrise.app/".$class_name. '.php'; //you have to use path relative to
                                                  // order or use a absolute path
                                                  // /var/www/.sunrise.app/
}
```

Also if linux system make sure the case of the classes match the case of the folder, since linux is case sensitive

Comment: Sorry, I added that to my autoloader and it didn't work. This is interesting, if I comment out my autoloader and use the older (soon to be depracated) `function __autoload($class_name) { require $class_name . '.php'; }` in my `init.php` file, error disappears and my page loads. But I don't want to use that one.

Comment: @enchance works fine on my linux system, are you including the `if` clause? if so are you setting it true or false depending on what your system is?

Comment: Even with the `if` clause it still fails. With my current folder structure, how would you guys do it?

Comment: @enchance You need to exhibit some problem finding skills. `echo $class_name` inside the autoload to see  if the autoloader gets called. Echo something in the class file to check if it is included. Use `require` instead of `include`. And please give us error messages instead of declaring that it does not work.

Comment: @enchance Is your script that has the autoload function being included before calls using the DB class?

Comment: At the very top of `init.php` is `use Classes\Sunrise\DB;` (after `<?php`). The use of the DB class won't happen until line 52. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @enchance ok i think the problem is that your index.php file is inside completely different folder so you need a relative path like `../.sunrise.app/` added to the class string or an absolute path. Edited my answer to show, the current path is whatever the path is for the first calling php script, in this case it is `./order` since that is where index.php is.

Comment: @user1853955 you're right, it's not being loaded at all. I don't know how I could have missed that. But why is it not being loaded when I added it to the page using `include`?

Comment: I've played around with the paths and it's still giving the same error. Here's what I tried: `include_once './../sunrise.app/ordersetup.php';`, `include_once '/sunrise/sunrise.app/ordersetup.php';`,`include_once '../sunrise.app/ordersetup.php';`, `include_once './ordersetup.php';`, and `include_once './../sunrise.app/ordersetup.php';`

Comment: you had the correct path for ordersetup.php which one are you using for init.php? `include init.php` wont do it as it needs to be relative to index.php so `require ../.sunrise.app/init.php` or like i said use an absolute path so you dont have to worry about the correct relative path to use.

Comment: In ordersetup.php, tried replacing `include init.php` with `include_once '../sunrise.app/init.php'` but still the same error. So far the same error is being displayed over a blank white page.

Comment: Did you ever solve this. My autoloader finds some classes and not others and I cannot see any differences - driving me crazy.